# Laravel 5.3 Route::resource without REST

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I upgrade Laravel 5.1 to 5.3 and have some problem with routes.

In Laravel 5.1 I have route like:

```
Route::controllers([
    'pages/{page_type}'     => 'Admin\AdminPagesController',
]);
```

And in controller I have methods like:

```
getIndex($type)
postIndex($type, Request $request)
getAdd($type)
postAdd(Request $request)
getEdit($type, $id)
postEdit(Request $request, $id) and others...
```

But in 5.3 when I created routes:

```
Route::resource('pages/{page_type}', 'Admin\AdminPagesController');
```

I got an error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

or

```
Route pattern "/master/pages/{page_type}/{{page_type}}" cannot reference variable name "page_type" more than once.
```

and it generate me route in RESTful

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not alternative to `::controller` you need to create separate route for each action if you don't want to use rest:

```
Route::get('pages/{page_type}', 'Admin\AdminPagesController@getIndex');
Route::post('pages/{page_type}', 'Admin\AdminPagesController@postIndex');
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `Route::controllers` method has been removed in Laravel 5.2, I can't find it in the documentation since then, and doesn't exist in the `Illuminate\Routing\Router.php` file in Laravel 5.3

You will have to create each route separately for your case. Or you can simply use the `Route::resource` method, what do you have against it? You can add extra methods to a resource declaring them before the `Route::resource` call.